# Insert calendar events with different dates through ContentValues

Tags: android

I am using the following method to add an event to calendar

```
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("calendar_id", 1);
        cv.put("title", "TEST");
        cv.put("hasAlarm", 1);
        Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
        start.set(2018, 3, 30, 8, 0, 0);

        Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
        end.set(2018, 3, 30, 9, 0, 0);

        long startTime = start.getTimeInMillis();
        long endTime = end.getTimeInMillis();

        cv.put("dtstart", startTime);
        cv.put("dtend", endTime);
        cv.put("eventTimezone", TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
        ContentResolver contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, cv);
```

The method works fine to insert single event. However, I have a list of events with different dates and different titles. Is it possible to put then in `arraylist` and all the events programatically?

Comment: I think you have to call it one by one i.e in a loop .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `applyBatch` method. Look here for [example](https://www.grokkingandroid.com/better-performance-with-contentprovideroperation/) and [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderOperation.Builder)